# Convert timer interval to float

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Is it possible to make **timer interval** to **float in c#**.

If yes then how?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this ?

Comment: I saw here: [Timer.Interval -MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) that it's double.

Comment: Does this not work: `timer.Interval = (double)floatVal;`?

Comment: float timerinterval = (float)timer.Interval.. :) slightly ambiguous question!

Comment: Im creating a program so i need the interval less than zero

Comment: Do you mean "less than one?"  A sub-zero interval makes no sense...

Comment: @user1436685: If the interval is less than or equal to zero an `ArgumentException` is thrown. What should a negative interval mean, that the timer runs backwards?? I'm afraid that you're mixing up some terms here.

Comment: perhaps the tick/elapsed event should be handled in an alternative dimension

Answer (score 0):

The timer interval is a double

Type: System.Double
The time, in milliseconds, between Elapsed events. The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue. The default is 100 milliseconds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that the minimum timer resolution is between 10ms and 16ms on a lot of machines, so it's the lowest delay you can produce accurately.

Comment: You should also post at list the link to MSDN.